# com.google.settings has stopped Micromax Android one

Tags: micromax, google-settings, android-one

I am using Micromax android one with Android 5.0.1.

Couple of weeks ago, few of my applications stopped one by one. Only two things I was able to do was calling and Whatsapp, probably waiting for their turn to stop. Recently it started showing `Unfortunately, com.google.settings has stopped`.

I tried to do a *Hard Reset*. On rebooting itself it started showing `Unfortunately, com.google.settings has stopped`. And now I am able to do nothing with the phone.

Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Clear the dalvik-cache & try again ;) Definitely there's a chance it'll work..

Comment: @GokulNC I have done that but no result.

Comment: you can try and update Google Play Services. It seems like all your Google app ecosystem is not working. Also, in case if you are familiar, try to share `adb` (http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) logcat output when Settings app crashes. that will help to track down why it is crashing

Comment: update the software using OTA updates.

Comment: Android One devices have stock ROMs available for flashing. You can try flashing the latest ROM for your device. Find it on XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/canvas-a1/development/official-stock-rom-canvas-a1-t2887150). Follow the instructions therein to flash. If it works, let me know so I can make this an answer.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I tried to flash a new stock ROM but it shows the message: *Signature Authentication Failure. Process Aborted.* I tried it with three different ROMs but same outcome.

Comment: FYI, Stock recoveries and Stock ROM zips mutually check file signatures, so one cannot be flashed without the other.

Comment: You should use the SP Flash Tools to fish the ROM, not the recovery. I asked you to follow the instructions in the post, and, FYI, you cannot flash a custom ROM zip using the stock recovery, or flash the Stock ROM using a custom recovery. Please **exactly follow the post**, it will (most probably) work. If it doesn't, then it's a hardware or driver issue. Ensure the PC you flash from has "Enforce Driver Signature Verification" disabled, or "Test Mode" enabled. (Google can help you as to how to do this)

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury appreciate for throwing light on that.

Answer (score 3):

A sureshot way to fix this would be to factory reset your device. I understant that you've already tried it from settings while the OS is booted and running. You could try factory resetting it from the stock recovery.

[This Google help page](https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/6088915?hl=en) will help you with what needs to be done. But do remember - everything in your internal storage will be wiped clean.

---

**Reset device in Recovery mode
Before you begin**

If your device is running Android 5.1 or higher, your device is protected to prevent other people from using it if it's been reset to factory settings. To ensure that it's really you doing the reset, you'll need to enter a Google username and password associated with the device after factory reset. If you don't have this information, you won't be able to finish the setup process and use the device at all after factory reset.

You'll also need to:

Wait 72 hours if you recently reset your Google account password
Make sure you have an Internet connection
Back up your data to your Google Account and be ready to restore
To do a factory data reset, follow these steps:

1. If your phone is on, turn it off.
2. Press and hold the Volume up button and the Power button at the same
   time until the device turns on.
3. Press the Volume down button to select "Recovery mode." If you need
   to navigate to the "Recovery mode" option, use the Volume up button
   to move the arrow and the Volume down button to select it.
4. You’ll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark
   and the words "No command."
5. While holding down the Power button, press the Volume up button and
   release it.
6. Use the volume buttons to scroll to "wipe data/factory reset" and
   press the Power button to select it.
7. Scroll down to "Yes - erase all user data" and press the Power
   button to select it.

Your Android One device will erase all of your data and restart with its factory settings. You'll see the Welcome screen just as you did when you turned the device on for the first time. When you're done with the setup process, follow these steps to restore your data.

Note: If your phone becomes unresponsive at any point during these steps, you can restart it by holding down the Power button for several seconds. If that doesn’t work, try taking the battery out and putting it back in and starting the steps again.

Comment: and if none of these works, them flash a new ROM. Easiest way.

Comment: @Yogesh I tried to flash a new stock ROM but it shows the message: Signature Authentication Failure. Process Aborted. I tried it with three different ROMs but same outcome.

Comment: @Dhaval Flash it using custom recovery like TWRP

Comment: @DhavalSimaria - How exactly are you flashing these ROMS? Try the factory reset via recovery first. Then let's dive into ROM flashing. Do not attempt to flash things you're not completely sure about. :)

Comment: @blueren I have done things step-by-step only. First I factory reset it, cleared dalvik cache, unlocked bootloader, then tried to flash it with stock ROM. All steps going well except while flashing the ROM from SD card it shows the error:  *Signature Authentication Failure. Process Aborted*

Comment: @DhavalSimaria - Where are you getting help from? XDA? Sig auth failures show up when signature check option is set to ON. I think it's ON by default. But this used to be the case with CWM recoveries. What recovery are you using?

Comment: @blueren Okay that was something new for me. Yes I was using CWM recovery. That must be the cause of the issue. Should I use TWRP , as  specified by Gokul?

Comment: @DhavalSimaria - At the end of the day, all recoveries serve the same basic purpose. Flashing stuff. It's up to you to try TWRP. It has a lot more features and support than cwm has. However, I'm not sure if there is official TWRP support for your phone. Please research on that aspect! ---UPDATE: Looks like there is [according to this](https://twrp.me/devices/androidone.html)

Comment: Everyone, a stock ROM can **not** normally be flashed using **any** custom recovery. See comment on question. If you have to flash a stock ROM, use a stock recovery.

Comment: @Dhaval, for flashing the Stock ROM, you **must** use the official stock recovery. First flash the stock recovery using CWM, then use the stock recovery option `Install update from SD card` to flash the stock ROM zip, if it is recovery-flashable. If it isn't, you'll need to use SP Flash Tools, as mentioned in the XDA post I suggested.

Comment: Quick check to see if the zip is recovery-flashable: Open it up in any archiver, e.g. WinRAR, and see if it has a `META-INF` folder inside it, with a `com.google.android` folder inside that. If this folder structure exists, the zip is recovery-flashable. Note: Both stock and custom ROM zips have this folder structure if they are recovery-flashable. Ensure what you are flashing is a stock ROM from the stock recovery, or try some CM-based custom ROM from custom recovery (flash via TWRP, CWM is ... unreliable at times).